# paginate while retrieving data cakephp with condition

Tags: database, cakephp, model, pagination

Currently, I am working on Cakephp Application. I want to first paginate and then sort the paginated data according to the condition show below or the other way around. First sort the data and then paginate it. Any hints on how to approach the problem. 
        I am just one week familiar with cakephp.

```
    $condition[] = 'Banner.customer_id  = "'.$loggedUserId.'"'; 

    $this->Banner->recursive = 2;
    $this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20,
     );
    $data = $this->paginate('Banner', $condition);
    $data_sorted = $this->Banner->find('all',array('order'=>array("Banner.created DESC")));     

    $this->set('loggedInUserId', $loggedUserId);
    $this->set('savecrit', $savecrit);
    $this->set('Banners', $data_sorted);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Banner.customer_id' => $loggedUserId),
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => array('id' => 'DESC'),
     );
```

Comment: I don't think it will solve my problem. I want to sort the data in descending order and then paginate it according to the loggedUserId.

Comment: See my updated answer. Now the data will come in descending order.